# Can Android Wear's Accelerator and Gyroscope and Heart rate continuously run more than 10 minutes?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors

I want to record Activities sensor and Heart rate sensor data for more than 10 minutes, but the app always shutdown when the screen off. Do you have any advise to keep the app always activate for more than 10 minutes?
Thanks for your help~~

Thanks to @solosodium, he's right, if you use **both Service and Screen On options**, Android Wear can work all the time till power off.

**Now**, There is a new question: how to reduce the power consumption? Ex: how to keep collecting if the screen if off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do any long lasting work (such as sensor data acqusition) in **Service** instead of **Activity**. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) for the difference of the two. **Service** will do the sensor data recording in the background, and your **Activity** needs to talk to the **Service** to get and visualize the data. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) for the communication between the two.

Comment: should I always keep screen on to make the data continuously collecting? I used **Service and Screen on options**, it works well, but cost lots of power. If I turned off the screen, the data will never collected.

Comment: The point of using a Service is that it has its own life cycle, which is independent from the one of Activity. If you use the Service the right way, even if your Activity is completely closed, the Service should still be doing the same work. Please check official [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for more info.